# Unescape characters in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, regex

Well, unfortunately I do not have any access to the source of an xml file which comes with unescape char which cannot be parse by LoadXml method, I wrote few line of code which replace special char present in an xml value to escape char. But, I think it not that good. Please help me to improve it.

```
private bool XmlEscaper(string inputXml, out string escapableXml)
    {
        bool isSuccess = true;
        escapableXml = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder xmlReconstruct = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            string firstFilter = Regex.Replace(inputXml, @"([\n\t\r\f\v])", string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline);

            string[] secondFilter = firstFilter.Split(new String[] { @">" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            ///***
            ///final filtration: separate every 
            ///node and value independently,
            ///transform unescape characters and
            ///reconstruct the xml
            ///***
            for (int i = 0; i < secondFilter.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                secondFilter[i] = String.Concat(secondFilter[i], ">");

                if (!secondFilter[i].StartsWith("<") && !secondFilter[i + 1].StartsWith("</") && !Regex.IsMatch(secondFilter[i], @"(<)(/)"))
                {
                    string temp = secondFilter[i + 1];
                    string[] cap = temp.Split(new String[] { @"</" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    secondFilter[i] = String.Concat(secondFilter[i], cap[0]);
                    secondFilter[i + 1] = String.Concat("</", cap[1]);
                }

                if (Regex.IsMatch(secondFilter[i], @"(<)(/)") && !secondFilter[i].StartsWith("</"))
                {
                    string[] split = secondFilter[i].Split(new String[] { @"</" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    split[0] = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(split[0]);
                    xmlReconstruct.Append(split[0]);
                    xmlReconstruct.Append(String.Concat("</", split[1]));
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlReconstruct.Append(secondFilter[i]);
                }
            }
            escapableXml = xmlReconstruct.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            isSuccess = false;
        }

        return isSuccess;
    }
```

Well, I tried with 56000 lines of xml file, not very good but does work, but is there any way to improve the code, the loop runs for very long time. Well, we can break the xml string to equal small parts. Please help.

Comment: If you know the regex to match the places which are not escaped, you could use `CDATA` and rewrite the xml to a valid form.

Comment: What makes you think yours is "not that good"? Just the performance issue? The more specific you get, the more specific the answers will be.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Yes, the performance issue. I need to improve it significantly fast for average case. Well, average case is like average length of xml files use in it/software industry. Because it check every value so, performance decreases with the number of lines and values presents in the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speed things up by avoiding some heap memory allocations, and don't use `Regex` for simple search. For example:

- Set an initial capacity for `xmlReconstruct` because a `StringBuilder` object defaults to 16 and doubles as required: `StringBuilder xmlReconstruct = new StringBuilder(inputXml.Length);`
- Use `Regex.Matches` instead of `String.Split`, then process each returned `Match` object.
- Use `String.Contains` instead of `Regex.IsMatch`.
- If possible only use `xmlReconstruct.Append`; avoid `String.Concat`.
- If you are processing multiple files then initialise any `Regex` object *before* calling `XmlEscaper`.